# Even a grid - Eva and Agrid

Tags: story-identification

I read a short story in the early 1960's (maybe!) in which, because the character had to stay in radio contact, he had to be careful to avoid conductive materials, "even a grid" (of metal).  His mnemonic for this phrase was "Eva and Agrid".  Anybody know this story?

Answer (score 5):

This is "[Don't Live in the Past](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56202)" by Damon Knight (1951). It was most recently collected in his anthology [Far Out, In Deep, Off Centre, Turning On](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rjOmBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT443&lpg=PT443&dq=%22even%20a%20grid%22%20and%20agrid&source=bl&ots=g8JdtXSsV2&sig=Q9OQhnizK43wJCt2y9eBVnCJxgE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Kc-iVNXZKYP4yQObx4KgDQ&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAw).

His mantra was "**Eve and Agrid**"

> Mazurin said weakly, Kamerad, Tovarich. Ami.' Then it occurred to him
> that these men spoke English and, anyway, they apparently didn't
> intend to shoot. Not as long as he didn't move, at any rate. He shut
> up and tried to think. What the Blodgett had happened to him? The
> metal floor of the cell was hard and cold under his palms. He was
> here, all right, and not on the end of any pencil of temporal energy.
> It had happened when the cell door shut behind him.
>
> He looked at the door. It was a grid of stout chrome-plated bars, with
> an interval between the bars of about three centimeters. A nonsense
> phrase came into his mind, 'Eve and Agrid,' which meant nothing. It
> wasn't Eve and Agrid; it was Eve and Adam. Eve and Agrid. Eve and
> Agrid. Eveandagrid -
>
> **Even a grid.**
>
> Mazurin shut his eyes and groaned. He opened them again when one of
> the guards made a warning sort of noise, and stared miserably at the
> limited vista before him. 'Above all,' one of the technicians had
> said, 'don't get yourself completely surrounded by metal, even a grid.
> It will break the temporal beam and you'll be marooned there ...'